# UITableView cellForRowAt indexPath events for next 30 days

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have this code below with Islamic dates (month and day only). What I'm trying to do is create a row in my tableview for events in the next 30 days. I tried the below but it's not working. I know I'm obviously a beginner and doing something very wrong here but I'm just not sure how to do it correctly then.

```
  var calendarDataSource = [
        "08/02": "SomeData",
        "08/03": "SomeData",
        "08/04": "SomeData",
        "08/05": "SomeData",
        "08/06": "SomeData",
        "08/07": "SomeData",
        "08/08": "SomeData",
        "08/09": "SomeData",
        "08/10": "SomeData",
        "08/11": "SomeData",
        "08/12": "SomeData",
        "08/13": "SomeData",
        "08/14": "SomeData",
        "08/15": "SomeData"
    ]





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "calendarTVC") as! CalendarTableViewCell


    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
    let islamicFormatter = DateFormatter()
    islamicFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd"
    islamicFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamic)

    let gregorianFormatter = DateFormatter()
    gregorianFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    gregorianFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    gregorianFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"


    for index in 0...29 {
        let nextdate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: index, to: Date())
        let dayInt = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: nextdate!)
        let monthInt = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: nextdate!)
        let yearInt = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: nextdate!)
        print(date)
        let dateString = "\(yearInt) \(monthInt) \(dayInt)"

        if let date = gregorianFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
            let islamicString = islamicFormatter.string(from: date)

            if calendarDataSource[islamicString] == dateString {
                cell.TVDayLabel.text = Array(calendarDataSource.keys)[indexPath.row]
                cell.TVEventLabel.text = Array(calendarDataSource.values)[indexPath.row]

            } else {
                print("no event")
            }
        }
    }

        return cell
    }
```

Edit: Adding what results of this
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciPTO.png)

Comment: What is your results? Can you share screen shot?

Comment: Yep good idea. Just added it. So it's just creating what the default .xib shows

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in your core loop. Islamic string is of the format like 08/12 but dateString is of the format 2020 4 9.  They will never be the same.  I think you want to calculate IslamicString for the current day, and just see if it has any data in your CalendarDataSource.  Like this:

```
    if let date = gregorianFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
        let islamicString = islamicFormatter.string(from: date)

        if calendarDataSource[islamicString] != nil {
            cell.TVDayLabel.text = Array(calendarDataSource.keys)[indexPath.row]
            cell.TVEventLabel.text = Array(calendarDataSource.values)[indexPath.row]

        } else {
            print("no event")
        }
```

Comment: So I'm getting somewhere here. The date shows up (although they aren't in order for some reason), but the value for that key is not coming up. And I believe the date is just matching with all the keys in my dictionary.

Comment: Never mind about the last part, that part is working fine. But I'm not sure why the event label isn't populating with the value for that key

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
```

with

```
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
```

and

```
    gregorianFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"
```

with

```
    gregorianFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
```

Comment: Thank you. I added this to my code as well as another answer and it's populating some labels now. I'll just send the same comment as I did previously: The date shows up (although they aren't in order for some reason), but the value for that key is not coming up. And I believe the date is just matching with all the keys in my dictionary now.

Comment: Never mind about the last part, that part is working fine. But I'm not sure why the event label isn't populating with the value for that key